# Salt length for a single password

Tags: hash, salt, password-hashing

So I've been reading about salt, and am confused about why the length is so critical. From my understanding salt is used for protection against pre-computed attacks.

Say I have a single password that is hash with salt length `n`. Suppose this hash and salt is accessible to the attacker. My questions are as follow:

1. If the `n` is too short, is the problem that a pre-computed rainbow table may already exist?
2. If `n` is long enough that a pre-computed rainbow table doesn't exist, what function does a longer salt serve? A brute force attack would simply add the `n` length salt to each hash it's generating. 50 bit `n`, 500 bit `n`. No difference, because the salt is known and simply added to all the brute force password values being hashed.

So to summarize, when trying to crack a single salted password hash, as long as `n` is long enough that a rainbow table doesn't exist, then the salt length `n` adds no security to the hashed password. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the function of using a distinct salt for each user is to thwart any batch advantage an adversary attacking one of many targets might have gotten out of precomputed tables.  If there are $2^n$ distinct salts and they're chosen uniformly at random for each user, it's only around $\sqrt{2^n} = 2^{n/2}$ users that a collision in the salts might happen so that the adversary might even get a chance to apply one precomputed table to many users.

- Pick $n = 256$ bits and you won't ever have to worry about it.
- Pick $n = 128$ bits and you probably won't ever have to worry about it even if everyone else uses the same hash function.
- Pick $n = 64$ variable bits and an application-specific constant that nobody else uses and you're probably mostly OK because the precomputation of the table is expensive already, even if there are a handful of collisions in a few billion users.  But consider revisiting once you've hit a million users just to be safe.

No need for $n = 500$ bits or anything obscenely large like that.